# How to stop Menu & Button enlarging & shrinking size on clicking (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, menu, anchor

All the  Menu & Button where there are Anchor links bubble up & down when clicking them.
Eg, when I click the submit button, it becomes big and then back to original size.
When I click the menu, it becomes small and then back to original size.

This is one of the submit buttions:

```
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                    <span class="elementor-button-text">CONTACT US</span>
    </span>
                </a>
    </div>
```

Would you please let me know how to stop it?
I'm not good at coding, so it would be a big help if you could give me full code descriptions.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are using elementor you should ask the creators directly (who may have a built in way to change this) because they have a lot of code running in the background so overriding them is a bad idea.

Comment: Hi fall3n: thanks you for your advice

Answer (score 1):

in case someone needs, I found the reason, :

I found `.woocommerce-message a:hover,active` in my css.
I deleted `active` and solved the problem.